# how do I deploy Django on AWS?

Tags: django, deployment, amazon-web-services

I'm looking to deploy a django app on AWS (since I have some credit coupon) and am looking for a good place to read about it - mostly b/c I never used it before. thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> looking for a good place to read about it

[Here you go](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/03/django-with-mysql-and-apache-on-ec2/)

Answer (score 16):

I am a developer at BitNami, you may want to take a look at our [free Django AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack#cloudImage).  It is compatible with the AWS free tier.

Comment: How can this not have upvoted yet? Bitnami rocks. I'm running their OSQA ami as well. Took like, 10 seconds to set up.

Answer (score 2):

2 new tutorials are given
[realpython doc](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)

and 
[Ashok Fernandez blog](https://ashokfernandez.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/deploying-a-django-app-to-amazon-aws-with-nginx-gunicorn-git/)

Comment: While the links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Procedure for deploying Django app to aws consists lot of configuration.In my experience "realpython doc" is the latest one.If the link become invalid, then you have only one option.Check aws deployment docs. `` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-prereq``

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to simply spin up an EC2 instance, install nginx (mysql? and any other dependencies you might have) then follow the steps on the django site: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx to deploying it. This basically goes through setting up a script to run "python [your app directory]/manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080" and setting up nginx to proxy requests to that port.

Another approach is to simply use a 3rd party tool like http://nudow.com to automate the deployment. For now the initial deployment I believe has to be done manually, however subsequent deployments can be done with one click. (and has other benefits like versioning)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [Nginx on an EC2 instance](http://ryangallen.com/wall/7/deploying-django-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to deploy your Django app ASAP, without scratching your head :

You can use this script that I wrote:
[Safely deploy your Django app in less 1 minute!](https://medium.com/@yask123/safely-deploy-your-django-app-in-less-1-minute-c1d67faad628)

**Instructions**

Installing the DeployDjango script

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yask123/DeployDjango/master/deploydjango.sh && chmod +x deploydjango.sh
```

From your Django App’s root directory (Where manage.py file exists).

```
$ sudo ./deploydjango.sh project_name
```

Done!

*Visit http://ip-address-of-your-instance to see your web app live!*